# NameError: global name 'twitter' is not defined while following tutorial

Tags: python, api, twitter, twitter-oauth

I'm a huge novice and I've been following along [this](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-delete-your-past-tweets-in-bulk-and-for-free-save-yourself-from-your-past-self-f8844cdbda2) tutorial trying to delete my tweets. Everything has worked fine til the end, when I run `python deletetweets.py -d 2013-10-01`

the error that shows up is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "deletetweets.py", line 62, in <module>
    main()
  File "deletetweets.py", line 53, in main
    api = twitter.Api(consumer_key="(my key is here)",
NameError: global name 'twitter' is not defined
```

I wasn't sure what to do next, so I cloned sixohsix's twitter thing and the same error keeps happening.

edit 1: pip list shows

```
altgraph                               0.10.2  
bdist-mpkg                             0.5.0   
bonjour-py                             0.3     
macholib                               1.5.1   
matplotlib                             1.3.1   
modulegraph                            0.10.4  
numpy                                  1.8.0rc1
pip                                    18.1    
py2app                                 0.7.3   
pyobjc-core                            2.5.1   
pyobjc-framework-Accounts              2.5.1   
pyobjc-framework-AddressBook           2.5.1   
pyobjc-framework-AppleScriptKit        2.5.1   
pyobjc-framework-AppleScriptObjC       2.5.1   
pyobjc-framework-Automator             2.5.1   
pyobjc-framework-CFNetwork             2.5.1   
pyobjc-framework-Cocoa                 2.5.1   
pyobjc-framework-Collaboration         2.5.1   
pyobjc-framework-CoreData              2.5.1   
pyobjc-framework-CoreLocation          2.5.1   
pyobjc-framework-CoreText              2.5.1   
pyobjc-framework-DictionaryServices    2.5.1   
pyobjc-framework-EventKit              2.5.1   
pyobjc-framework-ExceptionHandling     2.5.1   
pyobjc-framework-FSEvents              2.5.1   
pyobjc-framework-InputMethodKit        2.5.1   
pyobjc-framework-InstallerPlugins      2.5.1   
pyobjc-framework-InstantMessage        2.5.1   
pyobjc-framework-LatentSemanticMapping 2.5.1   
pyobjc-framework-LaunchServices        2.5.1   
pyobjc-framework-Message               2.5.1   
pyobjc-framework-OpenDirectory         2.5.1   
pyobjc-framework-PreferencePanes       2.5.1   
pyobjc-framework-PubSub                2.5.1   
pyobjc-framework-QTKit                 2.5.1   
pyobjc-framework-Quartz                2.5.1   
pyobjc-framework-ScreenSaver           2.5.1   
pyobjc-framework-ScriptingBridge       2.5.1   
pyobjc-framework-SearchKit             2.5.1   
pyobjc-framework-ServiceManagement     2.5.1   
pyobjc-framework-Social                2.5.1   
pyobjc-framework-SyncServices          2.5.1   
pyobjc-framework-SystemConfiguration   2.5.1   
pyobjc-framework-WebKit                2.5.1   
pyOpenSSL                              0.13.1  
pyparsing                              2.0.1   
python-dateutil                        1.5     
pytz                                   2013.7  
scipy                                  0.13.0b1
setuptools                             18.5    
six                                    1.4.1   
vboxapi                                1.0     
xattr                                  0.6.4
```

Comment: Impossible to say without your code. It's a scoping issue.

Comment: You have proably used python2.7, can you share pip packages, run this command `pip list`

Answer (score 1):

`python-twitter` package is not installed correctly, Remove the version number and install again.
Run the following command

```
sudo pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: added pip list above ^, and running that command gives me two errors [matplotlib 1.3.1 requires nose, which is not installed.
matplotlib 1.3.1 requires tornado, which is not installed.
Installing collected packages: future, oauthlib, idna, urllib3, certifi, chardet, requests, requests-oauthlib, python-twitter, six, python-dateutil
  Running setup.py install for future ... done
  Found existing installation: six 1.4.1
Cannot uninstall 'six'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.]

Comment: @skinny. Remove the version numbers, or replace requirements.txt with 
```python-twitter

python-dateutil```

Comment: @skinny. You pip list does not contain python-twitter, so its installation failed, try to run this command directly `sudo pip install python-twitter`

Comment: i did "sudo -H pip install -r python-twitter" but then it says "Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'python-twitter'" but when doing pip list it shows python-twitter on there now

Comment: @skinny. `-r` tag is misused in the above command, its used to download packages listed in a file. Anyway if the python-twitter can be seen in pip list, then you should be able to run the code